# Can router bottleneck LAN traffic over Ethernet?

Tags: networking, router, lan, cable, cat

Say I have a 100mb router and I'm using cat 6 cables connecting 2 PCs to the router, will I be able to achieve 1gb transfers between the 2 PC's via the network or will it only get upto 100mb?

Comment: So you have connected PCs with 1GB/sec ports to a router with a 100 MB/sec port.  You want to know how fast the 2 PCs will talk to each other?

Comment: @Pengiuns, sure your router could be a bottleneck, but generally speaking there are more factors involved that will define actual transfer speed - like computers hardware and software. So, this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: Both are running on SSD's with write speeds of 400mb/s internally.

Comment: Uhhh 100mb obviously

Comment: Simple concept, you can only be as fast as your slowest link.

Comment: You having a SSD, has little to do with bandwidth speeds, which you are asking about though. If you want a faster connection, just connect the two PCs to each other, that will guarantee the fastest speeds.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on the router**

There are plenty of Cisco 17xx though 19xx model routers that won't do a 100mbps.  Every packet will require a rewrite for source and destination, it's slower.  That's why they have the saying, "switch if you can, route if you must".

You won't get anywhere near your maximum throughput.  Just use a switch, then you don't have to add routes and configure interfaces.  If getting it done fast and transfer speeds are important, sitting around and configuring it is the same thing as using a poor transfer method.

Use a switch, for that matter, use a half duplex hub.  Routers are for connecting network together, not two hosts.